# How do I play sound on button click in android studio?

Tags: android, button, android-studio

I would like that when the button is pressed the sound file starts to play.I have already created the raw folder and put the .wav file there. The problem is that i don't know how to do this thing. I checked similar questions here but they don't seem to fix my problem. What should i do? Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;    

public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {    

int clicked= 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    //start


    //end

    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    text.setText("Score: 0");

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clicked++;
text.setText("Score: " + clicked);    
        }
    });
        }


        @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
    }
```

Here the xml codes :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="173dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/aidsv"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:text="Click me!"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="@drawable/redbottone"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Score: "
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:background="@drawable/sfondotempo"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp" />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
        Log.v(TAG, "Initializing sounds...");

        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);

        Button play_button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button);
        play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Playing sound...");
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```

Place your sound in res/raw folder.

Comment: Where should i add this code?

Comment: u can add it anywhere between your //start //end tags maybe

Comment: Yes , i tried to put it there but it doesn't work

Comment: Here the screen: http://imgur.com/jw2fks1

Comment: remove last line log and remove place your file in raw folder thats a comment not a code :|

Comment: Looks like a "smart quote" at the end of the second log line (the one with the squiggly red line beneath it). Change it to a proper quote and it may resolve the issue.